# How to escape characters in the RegexNER mapping file in CoreNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have the following line in my text:

> Mutation in the deafness (mitochondrial) modifier 2 gene

And I've tried the following lines in my RegexNER mapping file to tag **deafness (mitochondrial) modifier 2** as GENE but they've both failed

> deafness (mitochondrial) modifier 2     GENE
>
> deafness \(mitochondrial\) modifier 2     GENE

Seems that the problem is escaping the parenthesis characters, because it matches when I remove the parentheses from the text and the mapping file. What is the correct way of escaping characters in the RegexNER mapping file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses get transformed by the tokenizer into:

`-LRB-` and `-RRB-`

so you want: `-LRB- mitochondrial -RRB-` to match `(mitochondrial)`

Note also that the tokenizer creates a token for each of the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks as always. It matches but I get this in the entity mentions: "deafness -LRB- mitochondrial -RRB- modifier 2". Is there any way to get back "deafness (mitochondrial) modifier 2" or should I just replace -LRB- and -RRB- on my own?